# MIP SDK - What are the available UserRights in MIP SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to apply "PRINT" UserRight to ProtectionDescriptor but its not opening PDF file content.
Trying to find list of UserRights for MIP SDK. I tried "OWNER", it works. But I do not want to give "OWNER" rights. Any help would be great.

```
var newRights = new List<UserRights>();
foreach (UserSet userset in options.userSet)
{
   newRights.Add(new UserRights(new List<string> { userset.Users  }, new List<string> { "PRINT" }));
};
ProtectionDescriptor protectionDescriptor = new ProtectionDescriptor(newRights);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also include VIEW. VIEW is the base required right to open the content.

Full rights are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/configure-usage-rights

Comment: This worked. Thank you Tom. 
var newRights = new List<UserRights>();
foreach (UserSet userset in options.userSet)
{
   newRights.Add(new UserRights(new List<string> { userset.Users  }, new List<string> { "VIEW", "PRINT" }));
};
ProtectionDescriptor protectionDescriptor = new ProtectionDescriptor(newRights);